# VerifyUserTokenAsync() failed with purpose: EmailConfirmation for user XXXX1145-8bcb-48d6-b8a8-dcb75955b738

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I am getting 'Invalid token' error while Email confirmation in .NET core.
Above error is thrown randomly. Clicking the confirmation link for the first time is throwing error and again if we click on the same link email is getting confirmed.
Web application is deployed in Azure. Also in logs we found the below error

> VerifyUserTokenAsync() failed with purpose: EmailConfirmation for user XXXX1145-8bcb-48d6-b8a8-dcb75955b738.

Email Confirmation method is below

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userid, string token)
{            
    ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userid);
    if(user != null)
    {
        IdentityResult result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, token);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return Redirect("/Thankyou?status=confirm");
        }
        else
        {                    
            return Redirect("/Thankyou?status=" + result.Errors.ToArray()[0].Description);                    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect("/Thankyou?status=Invalid User");
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you figured this out? I also have this problem too.

Comment: Please accept the @Lajne answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, I solved it by decoding my URL encoded tokens:

```
var decodedTokenString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(token));
```

Comment: Thanks @Lajne, your answer is the solution

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user account is already confirmed. You can take a look at the value of `User.EmailConfirmed`.